# How can I match a string not starting with a sequence with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm running the following command:

`grep -REin "Example::" .`

I'm trying to filter my results more. I want to match anything with `Example::` except when it starts with `return` like in the case `return Example::`.

**MATCH**

```
if (Example::test())
```

**DO NOT MATCH**

```
if (something()) return Example::another()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could execute the following, using `-v` (invert-match) option.

```
grep -REin 'Example::' . | grep -vi 'return Example::'
```

Or use option `-P` which clarifies the pattern as a Perl regular expression.

```
grep -RPin '(?<!return )Example::' .
```

This uses [**Negative Lookbehind**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) to assert that what precedes is not the word **return**.

```
(?<!         # look behind to see if there is not:
  return     #   'return '
)            # end of look-behind
Example::    # 'Example::'
```

Comment: very nice, didn't know this +1

Comment: Just a note: this doesn't work with grep on OS X for some reason. Worked fine on my Ubuntu VM though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` to solve this:

```
awk '/Example/ && !/return Example/' file
if (Example::test())
```